# enterprise architect template editor select diagrams to appear in report

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am new to enterprise architect and the template editor and am trying to set up a simple template for reporting use case scenarios. What I want is to display the use case diagram the activity diagrams and the scenarios. At the moment I manage everything except activity diagrams using the following structure:

- Package

  - Diagram
  - Element

    - Diagram
    - Scenario

This codes does not display the activity diagrams. By enabling child elements under the diagram section in the element section I manage to enable activity diagrams, but it also produces headings for all the steps in the use case in my report. Does anyone know how I can select that I only want the activity diagrams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to include child elements and then in exclude filters select everything except use case and activity. The solution was provided by Sparx Systems support.